# Input field not aligned vertically into IE - ReactJS / MaterialUI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am facing a small UI issue here that is bothering me a lot . So i thought why not asking a question here . The problem is that i am using `material-ui` library to create my components . And this specific one is `<OutlinedInput/>` . But the result seems to be different on Chrome and on IE . So i wonder what property IE is missing to align the input text vertically .

```
                input: {
                    textAlign: 'center',
                    margin: 'auto',
                    minWidth: 220,
                    maxHeight: '35px',
                    fontSize: '1.6rem',
                }
```

[image]

Comment: <TextField variant="outlined" /> is working fine with centered align, why you need to do separately ?

Comment: what do you mean do it separately ? i just add some additional styles

Comment: I meant margin and text align, did u tried this textfield, it also having same issue in IE?